# Kendo PDF export issue for RTL languages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, pdf-generation, kendo-grid, right-to-left

I want to export PDF from Kendo Grid Using ASP.MVC, that's work fine but when the texts are in RTL mode(ex Arabic/Persian) its not OK! : [image]

As you seen in the picture, the orange buttons must show "ویرایش" but it Won't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTL content is not supported for PDF exporting:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#known-limitations

Comment: kendo is open source and here, there are many professional developers, there must be a way to do it.

Comment: @eFarzad  can you share your solution?