# Export to PDF using Kendo UI (issue with RTL languages)

Tags: javascript, pdf, kendo-ui

I am using given code to export html page to pdf by using drawDom method:

```
    $(function(){ 
        $('#ExportToPdf').on("click", function (e) {
            var selectedTab = $('.selected-tab').attr("id");
            selectedTab = selectedTab.replace("tab-", "#");
            var fileName = $(selectedTab).find($('.report-title')).text().replace(' ', '_');
            kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(selectedTab))
             .then(function (group) {
                 // Render the result as a PDF file
                 return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                     paperSize: "auto",
                     margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
                 });
             })
             .done(function (data) {
                 // Save the PDF file
                 kendo.saveAs({
                     dataURI: data,
                     fileName: fileName + ".pdf"
                 });
             });
        });
    });
```

But result is given below for Arabic characters 
[image]

I want this result:

[image]

I tried every thing what I get on internet.

Adding different types of fonts for unicode and kendo builtin fonts but all in vein.

Comment: Have you tried changing the styles for `<td>`? It seems to me that css prop `letter-spacing` is the problem, try setting it to ie `1px;` Also if you are using custom fonts, did you defined them with `kendo.pdf.defineFont` method?

Comment: I just now tried, but not working

Comment: It's nice that you tried it all on internet except kendo docs. It says: Right-to-left text is not supported. Also this is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488786/kendo-pdf-export-issue-for-rtl-languages

Comment: dear if RTL is supported then why I ask here? Here developers are more expert then kendo, I am able export this correctly in svg, png, excel but only issue with pdf

Answer (score 1):

This question is 8 months old, so you might have found a solution by now.
I just wanted to share my own solution, which is a bit of a hack, but at least it works for me.

Basically, you want to flip the text in the html using the special command: `&#x202d;`

For example - `&#x202d; grid.client.name` (grid.client.name is just an example, replace with where you store the arabic names. Repeat for each cell that contains arabic text).

You will notice now that the text in the pdf is no longer shrinked - but it actually has the wrong direction now. How to fix this? - well,
you simply reverse the arabic text in the code (so basically we reverse the text twice). An example method to reverse a string:

```
function reverseString(str) {
    var newString = "";
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      newString += str[i];
    }
    return newString;
  }
```

Apply this to all of your data that contains arabic text.

If you've done both of these things, it should now appear correctly after exporting to pdf.

Good Luck.

Comment: characters are shrinked also.

Comment: I'm sorry it hasn't worked for you. I'm using Hebrew (don't think it matters as it's also an RtL language which has the shrinking issue). After applying &#x202d; it was flipped but not shrinked anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is KENDO UI tutorial and it works fine for me.Can you rewrite your code by analyze this code? If the problem is still continue then we try to find solution again.

```js
<script>
    // Import DejaVu Sans font for embedding

    // NOTE: Only required if the Kendo UI stylesheets are loaded
    // from a different origin, e.g. cdn.kendostatic.com
    kendo.pdf.defineFont({
        "DejaVu Sans"             : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf",
        "DejaVu Sans|Bold"        : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf",
        "DejaVu Sans|Bold|Italic" : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
        "DejaVu Sans|Italic"      : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf",
        "WebComponentsIcons"      : "https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.223/styles/fonts/glyphs/WebComponentsIcons.ttf"
    });
</script>

<!-- Load Pako ZLIB library to enable PDF compression -->
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/pako_deflate.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".export-pdf").click(function() {
        // Convert the DOM element to a drawing using kendo.drawing.drawDOM
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(".content-wrapper"))
        .then(function(group) {
            // Render the result as a PDF file
            return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                paperSize: "auto",
                margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
            });
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // Save the PDF file
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: data,
                fileName: "HR-Dashboard.pdf",
                proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
            });
        });
    });

    $(".export-img").click(function() {
        // Convert the DOM element to a drawing using kendo.drawing.drawDOM
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(".content-wrapper"))
        .then(function(group) {
            // Render the result as a PNG image
            return kendo.drawing.exportImage(group);
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // Save the image file
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: data,
                fileName: "HR-Dashboard.png",
                proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
            });
        });
    });

    $(".export-svg").click(function() {
        // Convert the DOM element to a drawing using kendo.drawing.drawDOM
        kendo.drawing.drawDOM($(".content-wrapper"))
        .then(function(group) {
            // Render the result as a SVG document
            return kendo.drawing.exportSVG(group);
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // Save the SVG document
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: data,
                fileName: "HR-Dashboard.svg",
                proxyURL: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/export"
            });
        });
    });


    var data = [{
      "source": "Approved",
      "percentage": 237
    }, {
      "source": "Rejected",
      "percentage": 112
    }];

    var refs = [{
      "source": "Dev",
      "percentage": 42
    }, {
      "source": "Sales",
      "percentage": 18
    }, {
      "source": "Finance",
      "percentage": 29
    }, {
      "source": "Legal",
      "percentage": 11
    }];

    $("#applications").kendoChart({
      legend: {
        position: "bottom"
      },
      dataSource: {
        data: data
      },
      series: [{
        type: "donut",
        field: "percentage",
        categoryField: "source"
      }],
      chartArea: {
          background: "none"
      },
      tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "${ category } - ${ value } applications"
      }
    });

    $("#users").kendoChart({
        legend: {
            visible: false
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "column"
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Users Reached",
            data: [340, 894, 1345, 1012, 3043, 2013, 2561, 2018, 2435, 3012]
        }, {
            name: "Applications",
            data: [50, 80, 120, 203, 324, 297, 176, 354, 401, 349]
        }],
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                visible: false
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            categories: [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011],
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        chartArea: {
            background: "none"
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0}",
            template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        }
    });

    $("#referrals").kendoChart({
      legend: {
        position: "bottom"
      },
      dataSource: {
        data: refs
      },
      series: [{
        type: "pie",
        field: "percentage",
        categoryField: "source"
      }],
      chartArea: {
          background: "none"
      },
      tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        template: "${ category } - ${ value }%"
      }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
          read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
        },
        pageSize: 15,
        group: { field: "ContactTitle" }
      },
      height: 450,
      groupable: true,
      sortable: true,
      selectable: "multiple",
      reorderable: true,
      resizable: true,
      filterable: true,
      pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
      },
      columns: [
        {
          field: "ContactName",
          template: "<div class=\'customer-name\'>#: ContactName #</div>",
          title: "Contact",
          width: 200
        },{
          field: "ContactTitle",
          title: "Contact Title",
          width: 220
        },{
          field: "Phone",
          title: "Phone",
          width: 160
        },{
          field: "CompanyName",
          title: "Company Name"
        },{
          field: "City",
          title: "City",
          width: 160
        }
      ]
    });
   });
</script>
```

```css
<style>
    /*
        Use the DejaVu Sans font for display and embedding in the PDF file.
        The standard PDF fonts have no support for Unicode characters.
    */
    .k-widget {
        font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
        font-size: .9em;
    }
</style>

<style>
.export-app {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 750px;
    padding: 0;
}

.export-app .demo-section {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 0;
}

.content-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.charts-wrapper {
    height: 250px;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}

#applications,
#users,
#referrals {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 240px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#applications,
#referrals {
    width: 24%;
    height: 250px;
}

.customer-photo {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 40px 44px;
    background-position: center center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 41px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #999, inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.customer-name {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 41px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
 
    <div class="box wide hidden-on-narrow">
        <h4>Export page content</h4>
        <div class="box-col">
            <button class='export-pdf k-button'>Export as PDF</button>
        </div>
        <div class="box-col">
            <button class='export-img k-button'>Export as Image</button>
        </div>
        <div class="box-col">
            <button class='export-svg k-button'>Export as SVG</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="demo-section k-content export-app wide hidden-on-narrow">
        <div class="demo-section content-wrapper wide">
          <div class="demo-section charts-wrapper wide">
            <div id="users"></div>
            <div id="applications"></div>
            <div id="referrals"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="grid"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="responsive-message"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, This is completely copy and paste from Kendo Documentation. I already tried this but not working.

Comment: I have only issue with Arabic characters. I can export everything(charts, grids, html) except arabic character in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I made temporary solution that I convert the report into canvas then I exported to pdf. I html2canvas to export html in to canvas. if any one find another solution please let me know.

```
 $('#ExportToPdf').on("click", function (e) {
     html2canvas(document.querySelector("#widget-47")).then(canvas => {
         $("#widget-47").hide();
         $("#widget-47").parent().append(canvas);
     });
     setTimeout(function () {
         kendo.drawing.drawDOM($('#kendo-wrapper'))
          .then(function (group) {
              // Render the result as a PDF file
              return kendo.drawing.exportPDF(group, {
                  paperSize: "auto",
                  margin: { left: "1cm", top: "1cm", right: "1cm", bottom: "1cm" }
              });
          })
          .done(function (data) {
              // Save the PDF file
              kendo.saveAs({
                  dataURI: data,
                  fileName: "report.pdf"
              });
              $("#widget-47").siblings().remove();
              $("#widget-47").show();
          });
     }, 3000);
 });
```

Comment: I don't know that your problem is still present or not, but can you show us the HTML file to know that what is 'widget-47' and 'kendo-wrapper'.

Comment: kendo-wrapper is a parent div and widget-47 is a grid and you can make any numbers of widgets from kendo controls.